# can I run movie player in background when mirroring to external screen - objective c

Tags: objective-c, video, background, mirroring

I have an application that plays video from local disk and when a second screen is connected (through AV composite cable) it switch the movie view to the external screen. this is working fine so far. what I want is, when the user press the home button and the app goes to background mode; I want to continue playing the video in the second screen while the app is running in the background mode. this works for audio, as I have set my application to continue play audio in background mode and it is working fine: the audio continue to play in the background mode fine. now is it possible to continue play video as well, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. It is outside of the scope of an iOS app to continue powering a screen while it is in the background.